# How to close a mat dialog without a backdrop on clicking outside?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-dialog

How Can I close the dialog in this **[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg6v6)** **(Minimal, Reproducible Example.)** by clicking outside ?

This works fine if I remove the property `hasBackdrop: false` -> [Working Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg6v6-2wxntt?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell, you need to do your own click handling - listen to clicks and determine whether or not they are outside the dialog. This allows you to not trap the click event the way that the backdrop does. [Here's a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg6v6-gvv3gz?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.ts) based on yours:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this.clickoutHandler) {
      this.clickoutHandler(event);
    }
  }

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  clickoutHandler: Function;

  dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        width: '250px',
        hasBackdrop: false
      });

      this.dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {
        this.clickoutHandler = this.closeDialogFromClickout;
      });

      this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
        this.clickoutHandler = null;
      });
    });
  }

  closeDialogFromClickout(event: MouseEvent) {
    const matDialogContainerEl = this.dialogRef.componentInstance.hostElement.nativeElement.parentElement;
    const rect = matDialogContainerEl.getBoundingClientRect()
    if(event.clientX <= rect.left || event.clientX >= rect.right || 
        event.clientY <= rect.top || event.clientY >= rect.bottom) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public hostElement: ElementRef,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The standard approach for creating an [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) that closes when clicking outside the dialog box (while creating the appearance that there is no backdrop) is to use the built-in library CSS class `cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop` and apply it using the [`MatDialogConfig`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) property `backdropClass`.

The `openDialog` method would be:

```
openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
    backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
    hasBackdrop: true,
    width: '250px'
  });
}
```

See [**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57878327?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Comment: this is same as kevits ' answer . If I do that I have to click twice on a button once to close backdrop once to click the button

Comment: no i mean if there is button on the page now you have to click on the button twice once to close backdrop second to actually click the button. which is defective behavior

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't seem to work on outside of router outlet

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways on how to achieve this. One would be listening on window clicks. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg6v6-3tjqyf?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  private inited;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {
        this.inited = true;
      })
  }

  @HostListener('window:click')
  onNoClick(): void {
    if (this.inited) {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }

}
```

But I suggest you edit the css for the backdrop, so it remains invisible but the functionality stays.

```
.cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: If I do that I have to click twice on a button once to close backdrop once to click the button https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkg6v6-sxgzbz?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: If the backdrop is transparent, it indicates that the other elements are functional, so keeping standard functionality would be rather broken behavior.