# Transparent background in angular material dialog

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the color of the angular material dialog using css var (), but instead of the color I need, the background becomes transparent.

Css style:

```
.custom-dialog >  mat-dialog-container {
  background: var(--background);
}
```

Open dialog function:

```
openDialogForCreateDirectory(): void {
    this.dialog.open(CreateDirectoryComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      panelClass: 'custom-dialog'
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close a mat dialog without a backdrop on clicking outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878327/how-to-close-a-mat-dialog-without-a-backdrop-on-clicking-outside)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `::ng-deep` to force the style down to angular material components:

```
::ng-deep .custom-dialog > mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

See working example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ebnbevodyrv

Comment: ng-deep & co are deprecated and should not be used. Instead define such overrides in a special file and import it to your global style. In this way it is possible to use for more than one dialog.

Answer (score -1):

To change anything in angular-material library UI, need to add css in styles.scss i.e. root level.

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-cjzbdq?file=styles.scss)

Comment: In my case, this doesn't  help. My project structure is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dark-mode-with-angular-and-css-variables?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftheme%2Flight-theme.ts)

Comment: I can't see any dialog here. Is this updated or what?